# Handling Java stdout and stderr in Perl

Tags: java, perl

I am trying to run a Java program from my Perl script. I would like to avoid using System.exit(1) and System.exit(-1) commands in Java. I am however printing to STDOUT and STDERR from Java. In my Perl script, I am reading from Java's stdout and using that line by line output. How do I print stderr and fail if I ever see stderr? This is what I have so far:

```
my $java_command = ...;
open(DATA, ">$java_command"); 
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp($_);
    ....
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the perl documentation for FAQ [How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command?). This will brief you all the details about capturing and discarding STDOUT and STDERR.

Answer (score 1):

This has been discussed here: [**How can I capture STDERR from an external command?**](http://www.perl.com/doc/FAQs/FAQ/oldfaq-html/Q5.15.html)

So you can do something like:

```
open (DATA, "($java_command_with_args | sed 's/^/STDOUT:/') 2>&1 |");
while (<DATA>) {
    if (s/^STDOUT://)  {
        print "line from stdout: ", $_;
    } else {

        print "line from stderr: ", $_;
        die("Saw something on stderr");
    }
}
```